# I'm struggling to change my JS code to run URL instead of currently showing and output div

Tags: javascript

My JS below runs from my search bar and shows results in a same page DIV.  I would like to edit this to take them to the page selected from the search bar maybe even using a separate JSON file, or not, either way.

```js
$(function(){
  var url = [
    { value: 'Home', data: 'http://google.com' },
    { value: 'Guide', data: 'http://google.com' },
    { value: 'Examples', data: 'ttp://google.com' },
    { value: 'Themes', data: 'http://google.com' },
    { value: 'Download', data: 'http://google.com' },
  ];

  // setup autocomplete function pulling from currencies[] array
  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: url,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
      var thehtml = '<strong>Page Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.value + ' <br> <strong>URL:</strong> ' + suggestion.data;
      $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: What happens when you replace the content of your onSelect function with: `window.open(suggestion.data)`?

Comment: all i get is a blank search bar.  looses the drop down suggestions and remains blank. Sorry i'm not too proficient in JS unlike my css.

Comment: hm, I am not knowledgeable about the autocomplete setup you are using there but when you pass a url string into `window.open()` it should open a new window. Do you get a popup blocked message?

Comment: Its a plugin im using which works great as it is instead of #outputcontent div i just need the url to run.  do i delete the VAR theHTML section section.  Ive been wrangling this for too long now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window.location.assign to load the URL as a new document.

```
// setup autocomplete function pulling from currencies[] array
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
     lookup: url,
     onSelect: function (suggestion) {
         window.location.assign(suggestion.data);
     }
 });
```

Alternatively, you can use `window.location.href = suggestion.data;`

Comment: As an aside, you're missing an `h` in `{ value: 'Examples', data: 'ttp://google.com' },`

Comment: you my friend are a legend.  Works perfectly.  I wish i could see JS like i see HTML and CSS.  Thanks again